# How can I change/move the default folder that photos are uploaded to when using the Ubuntu One Files app for iOS?

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone

I used **Ubuntu One Files** on my **iPhone** and I enabled **Auto-Upload Camera Roll** feature. The app started uploading 500+ photos stored on my iPhone's Camera Roll, and it created a new folder titled **"Pictures - iPhone"**. Later on, I fire up my Ubuntu desktop and I see that Ubuntu One was syncing and it created a new folder on my home directory titled "Pictures - iPhone".

The questions are:

1. How is the *correct* way to move this folder into another folder (e.g: Pictures | Pictures - iPhone)?
2. Is it also possible to rename the folder?

What I meant by correct way above, is that I do not want to break the sync with Ubuntu One Files on my iPhone - I do not want to upload 500+ photos again.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Currently the iOS version of Ubuntu One Files is not able to change which directory uploaded photos are uploaded to**. I enquired whether this function will be added and was told that this should be added in a future update to the application. This functionality is already available to users of the Ubuntu One Files Android application.

I imagine that the procedure for doing what you ask will be the same as you currently do for the Android app, so I'll add the steps here and it should be approximately the same when the functionality is eventually added to iOS.

Firstly in Ubuntu create the new folder where you want the pictures to be uploaded to, then right click on the folder and select **Synchronise this Folder** from the Ubuntu One section in the menu:

[image]

When the functionality is added to the iOS app you should be able to select this newly created folder through the settings menu and all new photos will be uploaded to this folder. In the Android app this setting is located in **Settings > Auto Upload Settings > Upload Photos to:** The iOS options will probably be similar when they are added.