# Moving mobile phone Pictures directory

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone, directory

I use an iPhone and when Ubuntu One syncs my photos it creates a directory on my computer called 'Pictures - muffin' in the home directory (muffin being the name of my iPhone). My home directory looks something like this

Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Pictures  'Pictures - muffin'  Music  Audiobooks

It's weird and annoying that Pictures appears twice in my home directory. I would rather 'Pictures - muffin' directory just be called 'Muffin', but it does not let me, it just removes the photo syncing option I would preferably like it inside the directory 'Pictures' as well if that's possible.

Comment: What's the question? Do you want to rename you iPhone name?

Comment: So in short, you want to redefine where Ubuntu One syncs your data to?  that is to say, so that your iphone pictures show up in `Pictures/Muffin` or wherever on your system?

Comment: Thomas Ward: that is exactly what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change/move the default folder that photos are uploaded to when using the Ubuntu One Files app for iOS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93401/how-can-i-change-move-the-default-folder-that-photos-are-uploaded-to-when-using)

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented changing upload directory on Android. To my knowledge, this hasn't been explicitly planned for iOS (nor it was for Android ;)), but should be fairly easy for our devs to squeeze in. I will let them know about this feature request.